# storing information temporarily in php session variables

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables

Is it frowned upon/ a bad idea to store information temporarily in a session variable to give access to that information globally?

I have a file upload parser script that is called by ajax on submit of a form and I need to send back data at different parts of the script. I figured saving the information I need in different session variables might be a good idea.

Comment: That's not what session variables are usually for. There's nothing inherently wrong with it, but it doesn't make for good readable/reusable code. Why don't you just pass your variables around as parameters into your functions?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm very wrong with this: As I am using ajax to call the php file, I only have access to `.responseText` to get the results of my php script. That means I can only recieve a result from php once in that ajax call. I thought about using a JSON encoded array but that can only be echoed at the end of the script

Comment: I'm sure the structure of your PHP code can be written in a flexible way to accommodate returning all the information you need. Can you post your code?

Comment: It's a long and incomplete code so I saw no use in posting it here, there are many more flaws in it than just this trivial part! I will play around with it but I think, just for testing purposes, I will use the session variable for now until I figure out a fix. site is not live yet anyway so no security risk :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can store temporary data ( **not critical** data which compromises with the security ) as a session cookie in the clients' browser.

Comment: I can then delete the session variable after using it, correct?

Comment: yes, delete/unset the cookie one you use it